# Dynamically loaded web user control hides on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

i have a web custom control

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="WebApplication5.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlnew" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="ddlnew_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and on the Default.aspx page

```
<asp:Button Text="PostBack" ID="btnPost" runat="server" 
onclick="btnPost_Click" />
```

and on the Default.aspx.cs

```
    protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebUserControl1 uc =  (WebUserControl1)Page.LoadControl("~/WebUserControl1.ascx");
        PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
```

and when we select any item from dropdown it postback and the control hide from the page

so please help how it can be prevented from hide

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Dynamically created controls `must be recreated on every postback`, when you realise that each postback creates a new instance of the `Page` class, and within this instance you must re-create all of the controls each and every time, this becomes more obvious.

[Here is a good article on this](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)

[Another post on this that i answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432413/dynamically-create-controls-and-save-the-controls-values-across-postback-asp-n/5432613#5432613)

[And another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434521/adding-a-user-control-to-a-page-programatically-while-preserving-controls-alread/5434572#5434572)

To maintain state between the postbacks, you can use `ViewState` or `ControlState`

[MSDN Control State vs View State Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: how should i maintain the data that i entered before the control postback?

Comment: Use either `ViewState` or `ControlState` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: I am using user control which have asp.net controls in it that have viewstate. Now if i reload the control something like showascx uc = (showascx)Page.LoadControl("~/showascx.ascx");
                PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(uc); How it will maintain the data again in the new instance. Please specify

Comment: As long as you add the controls at the correct point in the page life cycle, this will be taken care of for you. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432413/dynamically-create-controls-and-save-the-controls-values-across-postback-asp-n/5432613#5432613

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434521/adding-a-user-control-to-a-page-programatically-while-preserving-controls-alread/5434572#5434572

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats really usefull

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void ddlnew_SelectedIndexChanged(object o, EventArgs e)
{
  ViewState["ddlnew_value"]=ddlnew.selectdeitem; 
}
```

than in page load pu this

```
If(IsPostBack)
{
    if(ViewState["ddlnew_value"]!=null)
    {
        ddlnew.selecteditem=ViewState["ddlnew_value"];
    }
 }
```

this should work

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, dynamically loaded controls require a bit of attention because of their behavior across postbacks. You must Maintain Viewstate for Dynamic controls across the postback or `check that on which control's is generating postback you will load the control or not..`

Check these articles ( Specially MSDN reference ) :
[An Extensive Examination of User Controls - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972975.aspx)
[Loading UserControl Dynamically in UpdatePanel](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/maintain-viewstate-for-dynamic-controls-across-the-postback/)
[Maintain Viewstate for Dynamic controls across the postback](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/maintain-viewstate-for-dynamic-controls-across-the-postback/)

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to enable view state on the page.

2) Like others in this post mentioned you need to recreate the dynamically loaded user control.

Here's an example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Render();
}
```

Render Method:

```
private void Render()
{
    var list = Helpers.Content.Lists.GetListByTitle();
    if (list != null && list.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        this.divContainer.Controls.Clear();
        var i = 1;
        list.Items.ForEach(question =>
                               {
                                   this.divContainer.Controls.Add(RenderQuestion(question, i));
                                   i++;
                               });
    }
}
```

Render Question Method:

```
    private Control RenderQuestion(Entities.Modules.Item question, int count)
    {
        // Create question control
        var q = (Custom.Widgets.ActionPlans.New.Question)LoadControl("~/Custom/Widgets/ActionPlans/New/Question.ascx");

        // Render question
        q.Render(question, count);
        return q;
    }
```

Hope this helps.