# Click event of Link button inside a gridview of user control not working when the control is added dynamically in a web page asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

On clciking a button in the page , I am adding an user control in to a place holder of the page.
The user control has a gridview which has a link button as template field and has a click event associated with it.

When I click the link button inside the gridview , the link button click event is not fired and also the user control disappears in the page.

Please suggest a solution

Comment: Sounds like the button is doing a postback and your not doing a databind on the usercontroll, but you are not giving us much to go by, could you maybe  post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--You need to recreate all your dynamic controls at the early enough in the page lifecycle (page_load/page_init), so the asp.net will detect events and attach them.

try this knowledge post
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794

[Why don't events of dynamically added user control fire on postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948533/why-dont-events-of-dynamically-added-user-control-fire-on-postback)

Comment: Thanks Sathish . It works after creating dynamic controls on load

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate your dynamic controls `on every postback` - remember a new class instance of your page is created every postback, so any dynamic controls you created the previous time will need to be recreated.

see [this article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)

[and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323408/dynamically-loaded-web-user-control-hides-on-postback/8323504#8323504)