# Event Handling of Server Control for Dynamically created elements

Tags: asp.net, gridview, servercontrols

I'm creating server control that inherits from GridVew.
I have some image buttons that created dynamically inside the control, for each button I have event that suppose to do something. 
Everything looks nice but the event is never triggered.
Here is part of my code:

```
//Class with dynamically created elements (custom grid pager)
public class GridPager
{
     public event CommandEventHandler PageNumberClick;

     //Element creation inside for scope
     for(....)
     {
        ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
        img.ImageAlign = ImageAlign.AbsMiddle;
        img.ID = "lnkLastPage" + i.ToString();
        img.CommandName = "Page";
        img.CommandArgument = ((totalPages - 1) * maxPageRows).ToString();
        imgBtn.Command += new CommandEventHandler(PageNumberClick);            
        tableCell.Controls.Add(img);
     }
}

public class MyGridControl : GridView  
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]

    GridPager.PageNumberClick += new CommandEventHandler(lnkPage_Click);

    void lnkPage_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
       PageIndex = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
       BindData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate your dynamic controls `on every postback` - remember a new class instance of your page is created every postback, so any dynamic controls you created the previous time will need to be recreated.

see [this article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)

[and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323408/dynamically-loaded-web-user-control-hides-on-postback/8323504#8323504)

Comment: I'm recreating them including all changed values, but I can't fire the events.